# Sleep-function in notification callback does not work as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a `UIAlertView` to accept some user input. But not all characters are allowed. When the user types in an invalid character the following should happen:

- background color of the textfield should become red
- text in textfield should change to something like 'Invalid character'
- 1 second sleep
- after 1 second turn background color white again and fill in the
  correct text without the invalid character

OK, here is what i have so far:

```
- (void)alertEditFloor {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:lang(@"ALERT_TITLE")
                               message:lang(@"ALERT_MESSAGE") 
                               delegate:nil
                               cancelButtonTitle:lang(@"BUTTON_CANCEL")
                               otherButtonTitles:lang(@"BUTTON_OK"), nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].placeholder = @"Something";
    [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].text = @"Some Text";
    [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    alert.delegate = self;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(controlTextDidChange:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:[alert textFieldAtIndex:0]];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UITextField *theTextField = (UITextField*)[notification object];

    if(![theTextField.text containsOnlyValidChars:[self getValidCharsWithSpace]]){
        NSString *tmpText = theTextField.text;
        [theTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [theTextField setText:@"Invalid character"];
        sleep(1);
        theTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        theTextField.text = [tmpText substringToIndex:[tmpText length]-1];

    }
}
```

The notification works fine. I tested it with breakpoint and NSLog. 
The if-block works fine too. Whenever i enter an invalid character the app goes into the if-block.

The problem is that the statements within the if-block are not executed step by step. First all textfield changes are executed and then the app freezes for a second. Because of that no changes are visible expect for the deletion of the last (invalid) character. When i commend the last two textfield changes, the field becomes red an the text says 'invalid character' and than the app freezes. But of course after the freeze i want the textfield to become white again.

Anybody an idea? Is there a problem with using sleep in an notification callback? What else can i do to make the changes visible for one second and redo them after that?

Comment: NEVER sleep or block the main thread, ever. Nope, don't do it. Bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never block the main thread. Your code never gives the first color and text change a chance to complete before the 2nd one is made.

What you want is to execute the changes after a proper delay. Something like this:

```
if(![theTextField.text containsOnlyValidChars:[self getValidCharsWithSpace]]){
    NSString *tmpText = theTextField.text;
    [theTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [theTextField setText:@"Invalid character"];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        theTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        theTextField.text = [tmpText substringToIndex:[tmpText length]-1];
    });
}
```

BTW - your code incorrectly assumes that the invalid character is the last character in the text field. Keep in mind that a user can insert text at any point in the text field by moving the cursor. The user can also paste in text and any number of the characters could be invalid at that point.

Comment: Thank u very much, works well! Thx as well for the advice. Of course u r right, i need to check the whole entry for invalid characters. I wasn't finished yet and wanted to solve the 'block-main-thread-issue' first.